# Notation for operational semantics that can be used in code comments

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, types-and-programming-languages, operational-semantics

I'm defining an intermediate language for a multi-backend code generator that I'm writing.  I want to document the operational semantics for this intermediate language in a way that is readable both from within the source code and generated documentation (ocamldoc).  The notation introduced used in "Types and Programming" languages is great for a book, but I don't want to try to do the prerequisite over conclusion style notation via ASCII art.

Is there a widely recognized notation for operational semantics that doesn't require non-ASCII characters?  I looked through various RFCs but can't find any that use a non-natural language way of specifying semantics.

Comment: The input format for the tool [OTT](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ott/) uses ASCII and looks like type/operational semantics rules. Maybe you could use that.

Comment: Why can't you use UTF8?

Comment: @Raphael, How does UTF-8 help me here?

Comment: @MikeSamuel: It has loads of nice math symbols that might come in handy if you want to write formulae. Of course, you'd need help users entering them.

Comment: @Raphael, oh, by UTF-8 you mean unicode.  Understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input format for the tool [OTT](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ott/) is based on ASCII and the rules look very much like type system/operational semantics rules. Maybe you could use that format. I'm sure that the parser for the input format is available as open source.